# Why libreoffice's =FILTROXML only returns #VALOR?

Tags: xml, web-scraping, libreoffice, libreoffice-calc

I am using LibreOffice 7.5.0.3 (x86_64) / LibreOffice Community in Portuguese.
I am trying to make information from a web page and for that I am using the following formula:

```
=FILTROXML(SERVIÇOWEB("http://www.scielo.br/scielo.php?script=sci_arttext&pid=S1982-88372022000300013&lang=pt ");"//div[@class='articleSection'][1]/p[2]/text()")
```

It returns #value! regardless of the XPath or XML I point out.

What am I forgetting?

I am trying to fetch keywords from a bunch of pages like that
I have already tried simple xml and xpaths, but no success

Comment: Not all servers support xml format and instead will return the server default format.

Comment: Any way to fix that?

Comment: Only is you can modify the server code and add an xml response option.